# How can I embed calculations on foreign keys in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, foreign-keys, innodb

I am creating two tables in MariaDB, one of which has a column that is a calculation of a foreign key. The simplified version of the script follows this format:

```
CREATE TABLE a {
pk     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
value  INT
}
CREATE TABLE b {
pk     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
value  INT,
calc   INT,
CONSTRAINT fk
  FOREIGN KEY (value)
  REFERENCES a (value)
}
```

It turns out that 'calc' is always equal to 'value'+1. When querying 'b', b.value is never referred to, but b.calc is frequently.
Should I remove 'calc' to keep third normal form, or is there a way to remove b.calc's dependence on b.value? Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE b {
pk     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
calc   INT,
CONSTRAINT fk
  FOREIGN KEY (calc)
  REFERENCES a (value+1)
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey jimmy, could u add a select * of the table outputs you are getting and then what u expect to get? i seem to be have  an issue understanding the question, thanks

Comment: Hi Jaison, this is more or less what I'm currently doing, running 'SELECT (b.value+1) AS b.calc'. But since I never use b.value by itself, I'd like to remove it from the table if possible. Thank you for your response!

Comment: I don't know why you commented (in your last comment to me on the answer) about how you searched or why you asked for links in it since you don't describe searching the way I said to search in my comment. I also very much doubt you have searched the way I wrote because you would hit duplicates. Eg this post does not even contain a "clear, concise & precise phrasing of your question/problem/goal". This post doesn't even contain 1 specific question. Also please don't ask more questions in comments & clarify posts via edits, not comments. (But don't invalidate reasonable answers.) Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foreign key has to have the actual value of the referenced column.

You can use a virtual (AKA generated) column to make a computed column.

```
CREATE TABLE b (
    pk INT PRIMARY KEY,
    value INT,
    calc GENERATED ALWAYS AS value + 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (value) REFERENCES a (value)
);
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I think this is exactly what I was looking for! Does this violate 3NF, though, in that that b.calc is dependent on a column that is not the primary key? I think that's a compromise I'm willing to make.

Comment: Yes, it does. But normal forms aren't laws, they're general guidelines. If you understand the reasons for normalization and why you're violating them, you can do that.

Comment: "But normal forms aren't laws, they're general guidelines" -- that's so true.

Comment: @JimmyB A computed column effectively gives a view of a table without that column, via different syntax. Anyway the problem with not normalizing to 5NF is that change validity must be managed; a computed column has the DBMS do that. PS Your question is, as one could expect, an easily found duplicate. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If asking, reflect research.

Comment: The fact that this is a foreign key is irrelevant to computing it as another column + 1.

Comment: Thank you @philipxy; I could not find a satisfactory solution to my situation in my Murach's MySQL textbook, the MySQL manual, or on the StackOverflow boards after a day of searching. If there are duplicates, I was not able to easily find them. It might be helpful to provide links here in case anyone else comes across this particular question.